# Linq if-elseif-else using linq query in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

In my asp.net application i am using linq. I need a help what is the syntax for if-elseif-else using linq in single line.

```
genericReportList =
    (from CD in list
    select new GENERICREPORT
        {
            CITATIONNO = CD.CITATIONNO,
            DATE = CD.DATE,
            LOCATION = CD.LOCATION,
            //STATUS = CD.STATUS,
            PLATENO = Utilities.DecryptData(CD.PLATENO),
            PSOURCE = CD.PSOURCE,
            MAKE = CD.MAKE,
            ID = Utilities.DecryptData(CD.ID),
            NATIONALITY = CD.NATIONALITY,
            SOURCE = CD.SOURCE,
            NAME = Utilities.DecryptData(CD.NAME),
            VIOLATION = CD.VIOLATION,
            STATUS = CD.STATUS == short.Parse("1") ? "Complete" : "Incomplete"
        }).ToList();


If STATUS = CD.STATUS == short.Parse("1") ? "Complete" : and 2 for "Incomplete" and 3 for "Void"
```

Comment: Maybe use a combination of conditional operators?  What does this have to do with Linq?  We'll need to see an example to be able to help you.

Comment: Do you mean in a select or in a where clause?  Write an example of what you want in pseudo code.

Comment: "if(status=1) return "Complete" else if(status=2) return incomplete else if (status=0) return void  "  Same thing i want to implement in linq in single line

Comment: Please look at the following posting.  It may be what you are looking for.  http://msguy.net/post/2012/10/29/LINQ-To-SQL-CASE-WHEN.aspx

Comment: select new GENERICREPORT{ CITATIONNO = CD.CITATIONNO,DATE = CD.DATE,
  LOCATION = CD.LOCATION,
  PLATENO = Utilities.DecryptData(CD.PLATENO),
  PSOURCE = CD.PSOURCE, MAKE = CD.MAKE,ID =Utilities.DecryptData(CD.ID),NATIONALITY = CD.NATIONALITY,
SOURCE = CD.SOURCE, NAME = Utilities.DecryptData(CD.NAME),
                                             VIOLATION = CD.VIOLATION,
                                             STATUS = CD.STATUS == short.Parse("1") ? "Complete" : "Incomplete" /// Here i want to display 3 things lik "complte" for 1, "Incomplte" for 2 and "Inprogress" for 3 ////}).ToList();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand why you are doing `short.Parse("1")`. This will *always* be 1. If you want multiple if-else in a one-liner, combine ternary operators:

```
STATUS = CD.STATUS == 1 ? "Complete" : CD.STATUS == 2 ? "Incomplete" : "Void"
```

If this is going to be used in the context of Entity Framework (or other ORM with `IQueryable` support), it will translate to a `CASE WHEN` SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question if I'm not wrong, is that you might be asking about where clause.

if yes then you can always use multiple where in your query.

```
example : 
Collection.Where(x => x.Age == 10)
      .Where(x => x.Name == "Fido")
      .Where(x => x.Fat == true)
```

more about LINQ query

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can just continue with what you already have.

```
STATUS = CD.STATUS == 1 ? "Complete" : (CD.STATUS == 2 ? "Incomplete" : "InProgress")
```

Answer (score 0):

There nothing wrong with writing your own method and using it in a LINQ query.  It will be far more understandable and readable than a long conditional operator.

Consider using something like:

```
private String GetStatus(int value)
{
    if (value == 1)
        return "Complete";
    if (value == 2)
        return "Incomplete";
    if (value == 3)
        return "Void";

}
```

Then you would call it like:

```
STATUS = GetStatus(CD.STATUS)
```